# Passing object reference as itself to own method explicitly

Tags: java, parameter-passing

Question out of curiosity.

Can you find any reason to pass object as parameter of its own method explicitly?
e.g.

```
someObject.someMethod(someObject);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Reason why this isn't legitimate question would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Consider a method to "add" or concatenate some object to yours.  In this case it returns the result.

```
public Foo add(Foo other);
```

You might want to add or concatenate yourself to yourself, where you'd call

```
Foo result = this.add(this)
```

Comment: A full-blown example of this: [`Currency.java`](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=254) line #200. *for quick reference* :)

Answer (score 3):

Uhm, sure. Just consider a class for matrices (say, of fixed size - 3x3 or so), lets call it `SquareMatrix3`. This might have a method `multiply` that performs matrix multiplication. Multiplying a 3x3 matrix with a 3x3 matrix yields a 3x3 matrix. Hence, the signature would look like

```
public class SquareMatrix3 {
  // returns the result of multiplying this with other, as a new matrix
  public SquareMatrix3 multiply(SquareMatrix3 other) { ... }
}
```

and if you want to calculate the square of some `SquareMatrix3 mat`, you invoke `SquareMatrix3 matSquared = mat.multiply(mat);`

This, of course, is just one example, there for sure are many others.

Comment: Check OPs example. He didn't ask for `this` specifically.

Comment: Oops. Didn't notice that.

Comment: That being said, if squaring is a common operation, it might make sense to define a method `public SquareMatrix3 squared() { return multiply(this); }`

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are reasons to do this. The called method might work with any instance of the class, whether it is `this` or some other instance. It would be a good way to write a method of a `Set` class that tests whether the set was a member of itself, for instance.

```
public class <T> FunkySet implements Set<T> {
    public boolean isMemberOfSelf() {
        return contains(this);
    }
    . . .
}
```

Comment: The method might not be static (like a set membership method, for instance).